# How do I know when to start a sentence with a verb without "to"?

Tags: grammar

How do I know when to start a sentence with a verb without "to"? Example:

> "Go tomorrow in the morning and ask Mrs. Baker".

But if I say:

> "To speak to Mrs. Baker go tomorrow morning"

Comment: It depends on what kind of sentence you're making.  Your first example is an imperative; have you looked up how imperatives are made?

Answer (score 1):

The sentences have different structures.

In the second one two imperative sentences are joined by the coordinating conjunction *and*: the hearer is instructed to do both things, to *go* and to *ask*. (Pragmatically, they are to be done in that order, but there is nothing in the grammar which specifies this).

The second is a single imperative (*go*), with a non-finite subordinate clause giving the purpose. The *to* is not just marking the infinitive, but also functioning as a subordinating conjunction with the same meaning as *in order to*. The hearer is instructed to *go*, but *speak*, is given as a reason for going, not an instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Are you telling someone to do something?  Then don't use *to* at the beginning.

> Go away.

Is the verb really a subject of a sentence?  Then use *to*.

> To go away is not what I wanted to do.

Also, it's possible, but not frequent, that *to X* as a preposition (where X is a noun) can begin a sentence.

> To the park is where I wanted to take the dog.